# Get textLabel from UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I need to get `textLabel` from row in `UITableView`. But I get `nil`. I need to get textLabel, because I'm using `UISearchBar`, if I will try to get data using index, when searching, I will receive incorrect indexes. So , I want to get `textLabel`. 
Please, fix where I'm wrong

When I am typing in `searchBar` items in `TableView` change. But index doesn't. For example `Food = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coca-Cola"]`. If I use `searchBar` and enter "Banana". Then I click on this , but I get Apple (because this is index - 0). That's why I want to get `textLabel`

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //let meal = foods[indexPath.item]
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let labelContent = cell.textLabel!.text
        print(labelContent)
    }
```

UISearchBar

```
extension FoodViewController: UISearchBarDelegate {

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    searchedFoods = foods.filter({ $0.title.lowercased().prefix(searchText.count) == searchText.lowercased() })
    searching = true
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searching = false
    searchBar.text = ""
    tableView.reloadData()
  }

}
```

Comment: Your question is missing a key part, which is, how are you showing the search results ? are you manually filter within the 'Food' array and then show that filtered result in the tableview ? in that case you should access the item inside the filtered array instead of the original whole array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never get data from the **view**, the cell, get it always from the **model**, the data source.

And **never** use `dequeueReusableCell` outside of `cellForRowAt`. You won't get the cell you expect.

In this case you have to get the data depending on `searching`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let labelContent : String
    if searching { 
       labelContent = searchedFoods[indexPath.row].title
    } else {
       labelContent = foods[indexPath.row].title
    }
    print(labelContent)
}
```

And your `filter` method is horrible. Change it to much more efficient

```
searchedFoods = foods.filter { $0.title.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored] != nil) }
```

Finally I recommend to change `textDidChange` to cancel searching also if the search text becomes empty and remove the unused items from `searchedFoods`.

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        searchedFoods.removeAll()
        searching = false
    } else {
        searchedFoods = foods.filter{ $0.title.range(of: searchText, options: [.caseInsensitive, .anchored]) != nil }
        searching = true
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I have figured out the problem is that you are using `indexPath.item` that's why you are getting the wrong index please try this

```js
let meal = foods[indexPath.row]
```

Comment: No, it doesn't help. When I am typing in searchBar items in TableView change. But index doesn't. For example Food = ["Apple", "Banana", "Coca-Cola"]. If I use searchBar and enter "Banana". Then I click on this , but I get Apple (because this is index - 0)

Comment: can u please send the code using for searching so i can figure out the problem

Comment: I Think you are using two array one for searching and other for saving something like this:-
var foods = [FoodModel]()
var searchedFoods = [String]()

Please use let meal =  searchedFoods[indexPath.row] in case of searching otherwise use

let meal = foods[indexPath.row]

Comment: And Use indexPath.row in place of indexPath.item

Comment: I want to try like this. But I don't know how to write a code. I'm new in swift. Can you write m, please. Thank you ! :)

Comment: I understood. Thank. Have a nice day ! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a text from the `UILabel` on tap of `cell`

confirm `UITableViewDelegate`

```
//Access the array that you have used to fill the tableViewCell
    print(foods[indexPath.row]) it will print selected row 
OR

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        let labelContent = cell.textLabel!.text
        print(labelContent)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets just say instead of getting data from foods (in didSelect method) get it from searched Food. But for that to work properly you should assign searched food with food initially and also when the user clears search bar you should again reset searched food to food data.

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if searching {
            print(searchedFoods[indexPath.row])
        } else {
            print(foods[indexPath.row])
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

extension FoodViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

```
    if searching {
        let food = searchedFoods[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = food.title
    } else {
        let food = foods[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = food.title
    }
    return cell


}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if searching {
        return searchedFoods.count
    } else {
        return foods.count
    }
}
```

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

if searching {

```
         let meal = searchedFoods[indexPath.row]
    let labelContent = meal
    print(labelContent)
    } else {
         let meal = foods[indexPath.row]
    let labelContent = meal
    print(labelContent)
    }

}
```